# Calling cider-refresh shows "Don't know how to make a localized variable an alias"

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I'm using Emacs 25 and CIDER 0.18.0.

I'm using `cider-connect` to attach to a running nREPL process. After connecting, when trying to call `cider-refresh`, it responds with "Don't know how to make a localized variable an alias".

I've tried debugging by setting Emacs to trace the function, and by looking at the byte-code compile buffers.

Loads of posts on the net refer to using `cider-refresh` so I'm fairly sure it should work.

How can I identify and fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CIDER version 0.18.0, the `cider-rename` function was renamed to `cider-ns-rename`. The code defines an alias for the old function that points to the new function.

The project I'm working on had a `.dir-locals.el` file (as well as my `.emacs` file) containing code that hooks to the old function name:

```
((nil . ((cider-refresh-before-fn . "integrant.repl/suspend")
         (cider-refresh-after-fn . "integrant.repl/resume"))))
```

Because these refer to `cider-refresh` (which is now an alias) instead of `cider-ns-refresh`, calling the function fails with the error message mentioned above.

Modifying `.dir-locals.el` and `.emacs` to refer to the new function (eg. `cider-ns-refresh-before-fn`) fixed the problem.